# Route, Routes doesn't work in React - Blank page in Browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-dom

I know this question has been asked plenty of times. But sadly after implementing all of the possible solutions I still get a blank browser page after using Route, Routes.

My Code:

```
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './components/Header'
import Footer from './components/Footer'

import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen'

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Header />
          <main className="py-5">
          <Container>
            <Route path='/' component={<HomeScreen/>} />
          </Container>
          </main>
        <Footer/>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thank You for for help!

Comment: Did you check the browser console for errors?

Comment: The attribute is now `element` not `component`. (Also, don't put other elements inside <Routes>): https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-jones-o12njm?file=/src/App.js

Comment: react router's v6 is very different, make sure you aren't following a v5 or even older tutorial. Always go to the library's own website first and look for tutorials / Getting started stuff.

Comment: What is the version of `react-router-dom` you are using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

- In `react-router-dom@6` the `Route` components can ***only*** be rendered directly by the `Routes` component or another `Route` component in the case of route nesting.
- The `Route` component API also changed significantly. There are no longer any `component` or `render` and `children` function props. They are replaced by a single `element` prop taking a `React.ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX.

## Solution

Move the `Routes` component down the tree to directly wrap the `Route` component(s), and switch to using the `element` prop to pass the routed content.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main className="py-5">
        <Container>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<HomeScreen />} />
          </Routes>
        </Container>
      </main>
      <Footer/>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! now I understand the problem. I am following an old tutorial, but working with new react. Ill keep that in mind next time

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't nest elements other than `<Route>` inside `<Routes>` component. When location changes, `<Routes>` looks on all of his `<Route>` children and choose the one that fits. You nested your `<Route>` element inside `<Header>` so probably that's the problem. Try to rearrange the structure and move Routes to the top level.